# How to get images from gallery without using image_picker or other packages in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I need to get all the images from a gallery without using image_picker or other packages in flutter.

I tried using image_picker. But it turned out that it cannot be used. And how after receiving the images to display a preview of the selected image?
​

Comment: I don't think it's possible. There are deliberate restrictions about third-party apps acccessing mobile galleries.

Comment: `tried using image_picker. But it turned out that it cannot be used.` Hmmm... That we do not believe. Please explain why not.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at how `image_picker` works under the hood, and inspect its native implementation to determine the native methods you may be able to use.

https://github.com/flutter/packages/tree/main/packages/image_picker/image_picker_android/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/imagepicker

See this page on how to run native code in your Flutter app (which you can also do without using a package):
https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/platform-channels

The question is, why are you unable to use packages? They should be easy to include via pub.dev or even as a local dependency in your `pubspec.yaml` if the former does not work.

To show the preview, I know `image_picker` copies the file to the app's temporary directory (which you can get using `getTemporaryDirectory()` with [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider)), after which you can show an `Image.file` in your app as the preview.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the MediaStore for image files.

If you have READ_MEDIA_IMAGES permission you will get all files on device.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do it. look at bellow code segment.

1.First you should make varible As `File` type.

```
File? _imageFile;
```

2.Then you should make a method for select image.like bellow,

```
  Future<void> _selectImageFromGallery() async {
    final picker = ImagePicker();
    final pickedImage = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    if (pickedImage != null) {
      setState(() {
        _imageFile = File(pickedImage.path);
      });
    }
  }
```

3.Now you can access images like bellow code.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Select Image from Gallery'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            _imageFile != null
                ? Image.file(
                    _imageFile!,
                    width: 200,
                    height: 200,
                  )
                : Text('No image selected'),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _selectImageFromGallery,
              child: Text('Select Image'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Full code part**

```
class UploadImage extends StatefulWidget {
  const UploadImage({super.key});

  @override
  State<UploadImage> createState() => _UploadImageState();
}

    class _UploadImageState extends State<UploadImage> {
      
    
      File? _imageFile;
    
      Future<void> _selectImageFromGallery() async {
        final picker = ImagePicker();
        final pickedImage = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    
        if (pickedImage != null) {
          setState(() {
            _imageFile = File(pickedImage.path);
          });
        }
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Select Image from Gallery'),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                _imageFile != null
                    ? Image.file(
                        _imageFile!,
                        width: 200,
                        height: 200,
                      )
                    : Text('No image selected'),
                SizedBox(height: 20),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: _selectImageFromGallery,
                  child: Text('Select Image'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
    
      }
      }
```

*****If you want to use filepicker try bellow steps,***

1.You should add some packages before use this method,

```
  file_picker: ^5.5.0
```

you can get it by using this [link](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker/install)

now you can import it like this import `'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';`

```
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class UploadImage extends StatefulWidget {
      const UploadImage({super.key});
    
      @override
      State<UploadImage> createState() => _UploadImageState();
    }
    
    class _UploadImageState extends State<UploadImage> {
      File? file;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Upload Image'),
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  file != null
                      ? Image.file(file!)
                      : Image.asset('assets/images/defult.png'),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      pickFile();
                    },
                    child: const Text('Pick a file'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      pickFile() async {
        FilePickerResult? result =
            await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.image);
    
        if (result != null) {
          setState(() {
            file = File(result.files.single.path ?? "");
          });
        }
      }
```

try like this you can now fix you'r issue.